# Primary key not found in OneToOne relationship with Hibernate

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I'm using Hibernate 4.2.6, JSF2 (Mojarra 2.1.13) and Tomcat 7.0.34 to develop my web application. I'm trying to define a OneToOne relationship between two classes using Hibernate annotations. I think I'm doing something wrong because I'm getting an **ORA-02291 Exception: integrity constraint (PER_VPT_F01) violated - parent key not found**.
I've spent almost 8 hours of my time trying to find where the bug is without any success. Please, could someone give a look to this code and tell me if I am making any mistake (four eyes can see more than two).

First my parent class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "GEN_MIEMBROS")
public class Miembro implements Serializable, Comparable {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "seq", sequenceName = "GEN_SEQ")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "seq")
    @Column(name = "ID_MIEMBRO")
    private long idMiembro;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "CODIGO")
    private Lista lista;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "detail")
    private Vpt vpt;

    // more fields definitions 
    // Constructors and getters & setters
}
```

Now, the child class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PER_VPT")
public class Vpt implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID_VPT")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "generator", strategy = "foreign", parameters =    @Parameter(name = "property", value = "detail"))
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "generator")
    private long idVpt;

    @OneToOne
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    private Miembro detail;   

    // more fields definitions 
    // Constructors and getters & setters
}
```

I must say that the parent row already exists when I try to insert the new child. In fact, I get the ID for the child from the parent table.  The thing is that I get an ORA-02291 Exception just when I try to commit the insert operation. As you can see in the image below, the saveOrUpdate() operation sets the value of the idVpt field previously.

[image]

One more thing. The constraint that throws the exception looks like this:

```
CONSTRAINT PER_VPT_F01 
FOREIGN KEY (ID_VPT) 
REFERENCES GEN_MIEMBROS (ID_MIEMBRO) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Was there any triggers associated on that table?? You can create only those tables in new name and test your code separately to identify.

Comment: Yes, there was :-( I forgot to check that. Now, I've disabled the trigger and the commit works perfectly. Thanks for your help. Write your tip as an answer so that I can vote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Marking comment as answer since it resolved OP's issue**

Disable all triggers associated with the table. This should work fine. Usually it happens with triggers, where it tries another insert/update